# Why is my form no longer showing up?

Tags: php

I created a contact form in a PHP project and I have been trying to get the mail to send and in the process I have been altering some code such as removing my contact form. Now I re-added the form, but it does not display on the browser:
[image]

This is the actual file called contact.php:

```
<?php

    define("TITLE", "Contact Us | MicroUrb");

    include('includes/header.php');

/**
 * PHPMailer Autoloader
 */
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


/**
 * Configure PHPMailer with your SMTP server settings
 */
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myemail@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


/**
 * Enable SMTP debug messages
 */
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;


/**
 * Send an email
 */
$mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('recipient@gmail.com');

$mail->Subject = 'An email sent from PHP';
$mail->Body = 'This is a test message';

if ($mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message sent!';
} else {
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>

    <div id="contact">
        <hr>
        <h1 class="contact">Get in touch with us!</h1>



        <form method="post" action="" id="contact-form">
            <label for="name">Your name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

            <label for="email">Your email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">

            <label for="message">and your message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

            <input type="checkbox" id="subscribe" name="name" value="Subscribe">
            <label for="">Subscribe to newsletter</label>

            <input type="submit" class="button next" name="contact_submit" value="Send Message">

        </form>



        <hr>

    </div>


<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: As a note: instead of requiring `../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php`, you can just require `../vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Could you possibly have a `display: none;` targeting the form on your css?

Comment: Something is breaking causing the whole form not to show. Are you including contact.php in your main page? or is what you're showing us contact.php?

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? Anything in the error log?

Comment: I had error reporting on index.php, but it is not displaying anything. What I am showing you is contact.php page. I have no display: none; targeting the form, it was displaying before I started messing with the code.

Comment: There's nothing there in terms of control flow that would keep the form from showing up. That means that something in your PHP code is causing a fatal error that ends the script before the form can be displayed. My guess is that the mailer autoload path is incorrect, but it's just a guess. You need to enable error reporting for this script and see what you get.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, when I remove the require '../vendor/autoload.php'; the form is back.

Comment: Hm, that's actually not what I would have expected. Without the autoloader it seems like `new PHPMailer()` wouldn't work. Maybe header.php includes an autoloader?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes index.php includes the autoloader. So it seems I did not have to do it again, could also be the reason why my PHPMailer code was not working.

Comment: I removed all the PHPMailer code and tested whether the contact form is actually submitting like this: if (empty($_POST) === false) {
  echo 'Submitted';
 } and it is submitting.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, go ahead and add your comment about the mailer autoload path creating the problem as the answer.